# Magento 2.3.2 - Very weird checkout cache issue

Tags: checkout, cache, forms, magento2.3.2, knockout

Hoping someone can help here.

We have a Magento 2.3.2 website. There's nothing particularly special, functionality wise about it. It uses cloudflare, which *could* be a cause, but the hosts assure us that the checkout is exempt from the system.

The website owners have reported that guest checkout customers are seeing random customer data values populating the shipping address form fields. We did some observation and experimentation and discovered that to be the case.

It seems to resolve itself when I clear the cache. However, if there's a guest using the checkout at that moment in time, then their details are then pre-populated on the checkout. It's the *strangest* thing and extremely frustrating.

I've gone through the entire codebase - disabled modules (including Amasty Checkout), reverted to the default theme. You name it.

Can anyone explain how this could happen? Has anyone seen it before?

Also, for the meantime, is there a way to ensure checkout form fields don't pre-populate? This shouldn't need to happen of course, but just for the time being while I figure this thing out.

Thanks :)

Comment: Hi there, I didn't get this issue on a magento 2 install, but I saw it once on a magento 1 project and it had to do with sessions. I am not sure what it was tbh (maybe something to do with redis keys getting mixed or smth), but i would maybe check this lead also.

Comment: I have seen this happen with the checkout cache on Amasty's single step checkout, possibly had some interaction with the same module's bundling system.